# htaccess file remove unwanted characters from query string

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking for a way to remove single and double qoutes from query strings via an htaccess re-write. I have inherited a website with some nasty urls and the new framework will not allow for this so it 503's I need to re-write so I can properly handle this for example I would like to change

2013/mobile-specs.php?''*Girls*&serialnum=2239

to

2013/mobile-specs.php?Girls&serialnum=2239

Any help is appreciated. Htaccess rewrites are something I have not been able to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule to remove all `"` from URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)%27+([^\s]+)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be removing the qoutes.

Comment: It worked for the given URL in your example. Can you tell me for which URL it didn't work?

Comment: here is the exact url: http://www.marinbikes.com/us/2013/mobile-specs.php?''Girls&serialnum=2239

Comment: Ok Is this .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in sub directory? Also make sure this rule is the first rule.

Comment: It is in the DOCUMENT_ROOT. All other re-writes in the file are working. Moving the rule to the top has no effect.

Comment: Ok I made an edit, try it now as the first rule on your .htaccess.